# How to perfectly fit Tikz grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=10cm, paperheight=12cm, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=2cm,] (0,0) grid (8,10);
        \node at (1,1) {B};
        \node at (2,2) {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does the above code (that is supposed to fit perfectly), leave an initial blank page?

Comment: You can fit grid in text area only if you from code remove `\node at (0,0) {A};` and before `\begin{tikzpicture}` add `noindent`.

Comment: Because your image is higher than `\textheight` for half  width of grid line.

Comment: I thought when the `1cm` margin is subtracted, the height is `10cm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your grid is higher for the width of grid lines (not for hal as I wrongly write in my comment), consequently it is pushed on the next page since it can not be fit in text ares. To demonstrate this, let us make grid lines thicker and semitransparent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, 
            paperwidth=10cm, paperheight=12cm, 
            margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=2cm, semitransparent, red, ultra thick] (0,0) grid (8,10);
        \node at (1,1) {B};
        \node at (2,2) {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Zoomed bottom right corner:

[image]

**Addendum:**
One way to resolve your problem is to reduce grid height for `\pgflinewidth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, 
            paperwidth=10cm, paperheight=12cm, 
            margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=2cm, semitransparent, red, ultra thick] (0,0) grid (8,\dimexpr\textheight-\pgflinewidth\relax);
        \node at (1,1) {B};
        \node at (2,2) {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, now image fit to text height and spill out on right border (as before) for `\pgflinewidth`.

Comment: Would that be solved if the stroke alignment was to inside?

Comment: You need to reduce grid height or increase text height for `\pgflinewidth`. See edited answer.

Comment: If I place a node in `(0,0)` that pushes the grid. How can tell the grid to ignore it with respect to its own placement (and not get pushed)?

Comment: @blackened, that is new question :-). Please ask it as such. Are you aware that your request leads to warnings `Overfull \hbox (... to wide) in paragraph ...` (this warning you already get because grid is wider than `\textwidth`).